# c# console.writeline error when adding the operator + " new"

Tags: c#, string, string-matching, console.writeline, method-group

I am using using the following code and I want to add a string to the output, but i get this error

> operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'method group' and
>   'string'.

```
     class Program
{
   static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string sample = "1a2b3c4d";
            MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(sample, @"\d");

            List<myclass> matchesList = new List<myclass>();

            foreach (Match match in matches)
            {
                myclass class1 = new myclass();

                class1.variableX.Add(match.Value);

                matchesList.Add(class1);
            }

        foreach (myclass class2 in matchesList)
            class2.variableX.ForEach(Console.WriteLine + " "); // <---- ERROR


        }


}
```

here is the class

```
public class myclass
    {
         public List<string> variableX = new List<string>();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to modify string before you use `WriteLine` method you have two possibilities:

- `class2.variableX.ForEach(s => Console.WriteLine(s + " "));`

or

- `class2.variableX.Select(s => s + " ").ForEach(Console.WriteLine);`

Comment: it's working Great . 
but in my big code it was only working when i made it like this :: 
( " " + s ) . the ( s +  " ")  other one was displaying what is inside the " " only

Comment: what could be the reason for that .

Comment: i also dont understand what .Select do . 
thank you very much

Comment: `Select` projects each element of a sequence into a new form [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb548891(v=vs.100).aspx).Or some [examples](http://www.dotnetperls.com/linq) of Linq functions.

Comment: so why it worked only on invers > 
 ( " " + s ) instead of ( s + " ")

Comment: Can you send part of your big code where it doesn't work. What type is `s` in your code? Has it defined `ToString` method to return any value?